# Flutter Passing a function to stateless widget not working if using RawMaterial with Textspan or recognizer

Tags: function, flutter, statelesswidget

If I'm not passing the function and just testing with print, it works. I have 3 functions passed on the widget, the CircleAvatar on tap works but not with RawMaterial / button

```
       RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () => bannerTap,//print('raw'),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            //recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap  = ()=> print('Text tapped'),
            text: info,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: actionMessage, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ],
          ),

        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function instead of function name.

```
onPressed: () => bannerTap()
```

Comment: the bannerTap is a function property I created on the stateless widget. I updated the question with a bit more code, please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Typo and just need to ensure the custom widget doesn't include the **(){}** functionName and only the property is passed